# port mapping using miniupnp and libnatpmp

Tags: upnp, portforwarding

I am using miniupnp to add a port mapping to a router, the port is mapped for a "lease" amount of time, I am using a random 10 hours at the moment, my question is:

after the port is successfully mapped should I ping the router periodically to check if the port is still mapped (for example every minute or even less) or do I trust the router to keep the port mapped for the whole duration of the lease, and only check few minutes before the lease expires to renew it ?

Similarly after a successful port mapping another call is made to retrieve the external IP address, do I trust that this IP will not change or should I keep pinging every few seconds (or minutes?) to verify that the external IP address has not changed ?

Comment: Any advise from anyone that had to write an application that required the use of UPNP protocol to open and forward a port on a router ?

Assuming the desktop application could potentially run from computer switch on to shutdown (for example as in Dropbox).
How long would you ask the router to keep the port/ip forwarded for?
Assuming an amount of time X, would you ping the router periodically to check on the state of the port, 
or would you trust the router to keep the port forwarded for the whole duration of X?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to UPnP event of WAN***Connection (PPP or IP) and catch the event "PortMappingNumberOfEntries".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot rely on Home routers to properly fire the right events in case the IP change or a mapping is not good anymore.

I advice to periodically (every few minutes) call GetSpecificPortMappingEntry() and/or GetExternalIPAddress()